# Integral $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_\pi^{2\pi}{\sum_{n=1}^k}\left(\sin x\right)^n\ \text{dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need help with this integral:

$$I=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_\pi^{2\pi}{\sum_{n=1}^k}\left(\sin x\right)^n\ \text{dx.}$$

The integrand graph looks like this:
[image: Graph of integrand]

I have rewritten the integral as $$I=-\int_\pi^{2\pi}\frac{\sin x}{\sin x-1}\ \text{dx}$$

But I'm not sure how to move forwards from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
I & = \color{#f00}{-\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}
{\sin\pars{x} \over \sin\pars{x} - 1}\,\dd x} =
\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}{\sin\pars{x} + \sin^{2}\pars{x} \over \cos^{2}\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}{\sin\pars{x} \over \cos^{2}\pars{x}}\,\dd x
+ \int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\tan^{2}\pars{x}\,\dd x =
\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}{\sin\pars{x} \over \cos^{2}\pars{x}}\,\dd x
+ \int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\sec^{2}\pars{x}\,\dd x - \int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\dd x
\\[5mm] &=
\left.{1 \over \cos\pars{x}} + \tan\pars{x} - x\,\right\vert_{\ \pi}^{\ 2\pi} =
\color{#f00}{2 - \pi}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

### Hint

$$ -\int \limits^{2\pi }_{\pi }\frac{\sin \left( x\right) }{\sin \left( x\right) -1} dx= -\int \limits^{2\pi }_{\pi }\frac{1}{\sin \left( x\right) -1} dx-\pi $$

Comment: Could you explain how you came about to this?

Comment: @WillSherwood the integral can be written like  
$$ -\int \limits^{2\pi }_{\pi }\frac{\sin \left( x\right) -1+1}{\sin \left( x\right) -1} dx=-\int \limits^{2\pi }_{\pi }\frac{1}{\sin \left( x\right) -1} dx-\int \limits^{2\pi }_{\pi }1 dx $$